# no IKE config found for X.X.X.X...Y.Y.Y.Y, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN

Tags: strongswan

I want to establish an ipsec tunnel between a Centos machine and my pfsense firewall. Attached, is the result of the strongswan status:

```
Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-12-08 17:56:54 CET; 2min 2s ago
Process: 1956 ExecStartPost=/usr/sbin/swanctl --load-all --noprompt (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 1939 (charon-systemd)
Status: "charon-systemd running, strongSwan 5.8.2, Linux 5.4.73-1-pve, x86_64"
Tasks: 17 (limit: 24877)
Memory: 6.0M
CGroup: /system.slice/strongswan.service
        └─1939 /usr/sbin/charon-systemd

swanctl[1956]: no files found matching '/etc/strongswan/swanctl/conf.d/*.conf'
swanctl[1956]: no authorities found, 0 unloaded
swanctl[1956]: no pools found, 0 unloaded
swanctl[1956]: no connections found, 0 unloaded
systemd[1]: Started strongSwan IPsec IKEv1/IKEv2 daemon using swanctl.
charon-systemd[1939]: received packet: from Y.Y.Y.Y[500] to X.X.X.X[500] (464 bytes)
charon-systemd[1939]: parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(>
charon-systemd[1939]: no IKE config found for X.X.X.X...Y.Y.Y.Y, sending NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
charon-systemd[1939]: generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]
charon-systemd[1939]: sending packet: from X.X.X.X[500] to Y.Y.Y.Y[500] (36 bytes)
```

Any help please.

Comment: You don't seem to have any connections loaded (`no connections found`). Did you configure anything in `swanctl.conf`?

Comment: Thank you for your response ecdsa.  
I  didn't configure my swanctl.conf.  But I have configured ipsec.conf.
What I have to configure ins swanctl.conf ??

Comment: You are using _charon-systemd_, which can't be configured via the legacy ipsec.conf. See [here](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConfigurationFiles) for more information.

Comment: Please, is there any solution to make my strogswan.service  use ipsec.conf and no swanctl.conf ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. But there exists a systemd service unit called strongswan-starter, which uses the legacy starter daemon and stroke interface for a configuration via ipsec.conf. You may be able to use it if there is a package for CentOS that provides it. But it might be easier to just to use swanctl.conf.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I configured swantctl.conf.